# How to make jquery ajax request to call function ChangeLoginStatus?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I work on asp.net razor page . I need to make ajax request to call function

`ChangeLoginStatus` and return value on `LoginStatusMsg`

```
    [BindProperty]
    public string LoginStatusMsg { get; set; }

   [HttpGet]

        public JsonResult OnGetChangeLoginStatus(string UserId)
        {
          
            string strHost = _ISecurityService.GetPCName();
            DataSet ds = _IUserSecurity.ChangeLoginStatus(UserId, strNewStatus, UserId, strHost);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() != "0")
                {
                    LoginStatusMsg = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
                }
             


            }

            return new JsonResult(LoginStatusMsg);

        }
```

on razor cshtml

```
<span class="spn col-lg-2">Account Status : @Model.LoginStatusMsg</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,`[HttpGet]` attribute shouldn't be applied to Razor Page handler method,just remove it

If you want to hit OnGetChangeLoginStatus method ,you need a url like:

```
 var url = '/YourPageName?handler=ChangeLoginStatus&UserId=xxx';
```

A minimal example in default razor page project ,Privacy Page:

```
<span class="spn col-lg-2">Account Status : @Model.LoginStatusMsg</span>


<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var turl = '/Privacy?handler=ChangeLoginStatus&UserId=2';
    $("body").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: turl,

            success: function (data) {
                var message = "Account Status :" + data
                console.log(message)
                $("span").html(message)

            }
        });
    });
    
</script>
```

Handler:

```
[BindProperty]
        public string LoginStatusMsg { get; set; } = "Msg";
       
        

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public JsonResult OnGetChangeLoginStatus(string UserId)
        {
            return new JsonResult("NewMessage");
        }
```

Result:

[image]